# Process form submit response from express server with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express

(Please correct my terminology if it's not correct.)

My files **server.js**, **run.js** and **index.html**, are in the same directory.

**server.js**

Sets up the server.

```
const express   = require('express');
const path      = require('path');
const run       = require('./run.js');

var app = express();

app.get('/index.html', function(req, res){  
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html')); 
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.redirect('index.html');
});

app.post('/run', async function(req, res){      
    var data = await run.run(); 
    res.json(data); 
});

app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Dev app listening on port 5000');
});
```

**run.js**

Will contain functions that consumes time. Here just one function as example:

```
async function run(){
    //do time consuming stuff
    var data = {
        "status" : "ok",
        "a1" : 1,
        "a2" : 2        
    };      
    return data;
}

module.exports = {
    run:run
}
```

**index.html**

Simple form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <form id="search-form" action="/run" method="post">
        Input:<br>
        <input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" value = ""> <br>
        <input type="submit" value = "Run">
    </form>

    <script></script>

    <div id="data"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

When I run the server, go to `localhost:5000` in the browser, and click the *run* button, I get redirected to a page just showing the content of `data`.

What I would like to happen when I click the the *run* button is;

- The server process `/run` post request
- A response is sent with `res.json` or `res.send` to the client
- A javascript script on the client side should catch the response, process it, and make some change to the html code (in my case, create some table).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hi Remi generally this is normal behavior. If you want to achieve what you wrote you should use smth like this: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ or  equivalent in pure Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is that you're using a form. Forms will redirect you to the specified web page with all of the form's data.

You need an [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "/run", true);
xhr.send();
```

If you ever need the data of your form to be submitted as well, I have some [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) on how to do that.

Hope this helps!